# Questions asking multiple things

Tags: discussion, answers, specific-question

This question [asking about two separate typefaces and the fonts that accompany them](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/25984/what-fonts-are-these-t-shirts-im-a-wild-one-aint-nobody-got-time-for-that) has two answers. Both of them answer a separate part of the question.

I think that the answers need to be combined in some fashion to truely be a correct answer for the OP or the question should be split up. (I've already flagged it)

How should we handle questions like these? Asking the person to split the question up into multiples could be considered spam if they have to split a question into several.

Comment: *Asking the person to split the question up into multiples could be considered spam if they have to split a question into several.* – Asking multiple questions far from what is considered spam on Stack Exchange or the Internet in general. It may be considered obnoxious by some forum communities (which I never got), but this site is not a forum, let alone such a one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, this should have been two questions. The asker has not been back to the site in over a week, so asking them to split the question probably won't get anywhere. Since this is a font identification of very limited use, I don't think there will be much benefit to take any moderation action to make it right (and there's no "move this answer to another question" function available to me).

In the future, I would ask them to split it up and post two separate questions. There has been a case like this before where someone asked a bunch of questions in one post, but then split it into posts (see [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/posts/17162/revisions))

Comment: Was that question split into 10 separate questions? How was that not considered spam?

Comment: The user narrowed it down to three and instead posted two new questions. [Yisela did eventually nudge him to reconsider other options before posting them to the site](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/17175/identify-font-for-the-logo-of-the-french-website-psychologies-com#comment23274_17175 "Your font-identification attempts don't seem very successful, this is your 9th question in a row. Please try to exhaust your available tools before asking new ones, as these are not really contributing to the site. We don't mind helping, but it sounds like we are doing your job for you.")